# TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'signal' - Django signals

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-signals

I'm trying to create a simple signal which prints something after a new object of the `Staff` model is saved in the Django-admin. The MVC python files live in `AppName`. Here is the code in each file:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import Signal
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from AppName.signals import printfunction
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class Staff(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = 'auth'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users - Staff'

Signal.connect(printfunction, signal=signals.post_save, sender=Staff)
```

**signals.py**

```
def printfunction(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
    print ("signal alpha!")
```

However it is raising the following exception:
        `TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'signal'`

I followed the [1.8 django documentation on signals.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch) Why is this error occurring and how to fix it?

Comment: see documentation again.. syntax doesnot have any arguement 'signal':
Signal.connect(receiver[, sender=None, weak=True, dispatch_uid=None])

Comment: Yeah, the comma and the '[' gave an error when I tried so I reverted back to dispatcher's syntax for Signal

Comment: so is it working now/?

Comment: okay if signal shouldn't be there, where do I define the post_save action?

Comment: it isn't working.. the present code gave this error

Comment: post_save.connect(printfunction, sender=Staff, dispatch_uid="''") in your models.py

Comment: okay now it didn't raise any exception but it didn't print anything either..

Comment: for this you can definitely use pdb to debug if the signal is being invoked or not

Comment: Where do you expect the output of the print statement? Are you sure you have a `Staff` instance, and not e.g. a `User` instance?

Comment: the output is displayed in PowerShell..

Comment: Is your function in `post_save.receivers`? Which code should trigger the signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Signal.connect(receiver[, sender=None, weak=True, dispatch_uid=None])
```

This is a very common notation for documentation. It is not literal code that can be used as-is. The arguments in between `[` and `]` are optional, if you leave them out they will use the default values. `connect` is a method on the class `Signal`. Unless otherwise specified, you can assume it is an instance method. Instead of literally calling `Signal.connect()`, you should call `signal_instance.connect()`, where `signal_instance` is of course an instance of the `Signal` class.

In this case, `signals.post_save` is an instance of `Signal`, and it's the instance to which you want to connect your function. The `receiver` argument is required, and in this case it is your function `printfunction`. `sender`, `weak` and `dispatch_uid` are all optional. In your example you're only passing in `Staff` as the `sender`, and you leave the other arguments as their default values. So, your final function call should look like this:

```
signals.post_save.connect(printfunction, sender=Staff)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's its the right way to do it:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Staff)
def printfunction(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
  print ("signal alpha!")
```